# how to load my style file instead of generic.xaml while applying style in window wpf

Tags: wpf, styles, themes

I have WPF project, in which i have applied style from another assembly in window for entire application. But, one of my custom control which is used inside the application doesn't take the style. It's style get always loaded from generic.xaml.

In this custom control class, I have set the DefaultStyleKey property and also the external style file gets added in merged dictionary of Application's resource dictionary. Can anyone face this kind of issue?

Note: Style for other controls gets applied from another aasembly

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication_CalenderEdit.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication_CalenderEdit"   
    xmlns:thirdParty=""
    mc:Ignorable="d" thirdParty.Style="ThemeNew"
    xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
  Title="Calendar Sample" Height="450" Width="625"  >
<!--<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>

</Window.DataContext>-->
<Grid  >
    <!--<DockPanel>-->
    <StackPanel >

        <Calendar WeekNumberForeground="Red" Padding="10"  />
      <ComboBox Margin="20" Height="35" Width="150"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: How did you "appy the style from another assembly in window for entire application"? Do the same for the custom control.

Comment: I have my theme file in third party library. I included it's assembly in my project and setting style globally in window

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly apply the same `Style` also for your custom window, e.g.:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomStyle}" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomWindow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomStyle}" />
```

Comment: Am not using custom window, I have set style in the window from which style get applied to all the controls defined inside the window

Comment: @Keerthana: Please post your XAML to clarify your issue.

Comment: posted the xaml code, also style gets applied when it is set directly to the control example: <Calendar thridParty="ThemeNew"/>